# outofmemory error due to quartz scheduler when deploying grails project war on weblogic server 10.3.6

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, war, weblogic-10.x, permgen

When I deploy my grails application war on weblogic server (I am using Quartz scheduling)
I get the permgen space error when I deploy it on weblogic. the application works fine from IDE or tomcat deployment of WAR.
 the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-one_MisfireHandler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Answer (score 1):

The tomcat server your IDE is using my be configured differently than the Weblogic server your using in production.  The first thing you should check is the JVM options the server is using.

Generally speaking the below JVM options should work for you assuming you have around 1.5gb of ram available.

`-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

The MaxPermSize is really the focus here but lets make sure we're using around 1gb of ram for the app (Xms and Xmx).  If you have more then make them bigger!

If your unsure how to set or even check what the current values are, google around and get to know your application server a little better as well as other JVM options.

Enjoy